# Получение только связанных данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, pdo

Одна база используется сразу же несколькими сайтами. В таблице sites есть список всех авторизованных сайтов, которые имеют доступ к базе, у каждого сайта свой id.

В каждой таблице есть колонка site, которая содержит id сайта, к которой та или иная запись относится.

**Вопрос**. Можно ли каким-то образом автоматически получать и работать только со своей порцией данных, чтобы каждый раз в каждом запросе не писать WHERE site = ...?

Спрашиваю не для того, чтобы облегчить себе жизнь, а для того, чтобы узнать есть ли такие возможности вообще, чтобы не делать то, чего делать не нужно.

Comment: Да, разумеется все таблицы связаны через этот самый id.

Comment: В MySQL нет управления правами на уровне отдельной записи. Так что увы... Но возникает вопрос - если одна запись доступна строго одному сайту, то какой был смысл валить всё в одну таблицу?

Comment: Такая структура приложения. Количество веб-сайтов неограниченное, и может то уменьшаться, то увеличиваться. Вместо того, чтобы создавать новые базы для каждого сайта, было принято решение использовать одну для всех с индексацией по полям, которые и отвечают за то, какому конкретно сайту принадлежит та или иная запись.

Answer (score 2):

В развитие идеи [@Dmitry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180398/dmitry) о вьювах, с целью снять проблему заведения для каждого сайта отдельного пользователя. Исполняемый код, обращающийся к БД, знает, для какого именно сайта он выполняет запрос. Однако автор хочет избежать постоянной передачи имени сайта (неважно, как параметра запроса или статически). Вроде имя сайта можно было бы содержать в сессионной переменной - но в представлении переменные не допускаются.

Решением может быть пользовательская функция, возвращающая значение переменной, которая в представлении допустима. Типа

```
CREATE FUNCTION getsite() 
DETERMINISTIC 
NO SQL
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
RETURN @site;
```

и соответственно

```
CREATE VIEW sitedata()
AS
SELECT * 
FROM alldata
WHERE site = getsite();
```

Тогда при установлении соединения мы сразу инициализируем сессионную переменную, типа

```
SET @site = 'www.mysite.ru'
```

и обращаемся к вьювам, которые в рамках нашего соединения будут получать только данные для установленного в переменной сайта.

Костыль, конечно... и надо проверить, как оно себя поведёт при разрыве и автовосстановлении соединения... и совсем неприменимо, если используется пул соединений.

Answer (score 1):

Без схемы данных сложно сказать что-то осмысленное. В текущей формулировке вопроса я бы предложил сделать следующее:

1. Каждый сайт коннектится к БД со своим собственным логином
2. В запрос вставляете `where site = current_user()` (так кажется в mysql определяется текущий пользователь)
3. Можно еще сделать view и вставить условие туда, тогда один и тот же запрос `select * from my_view` будет возвращать каждому пользователю только его данные.

Comment: Я этого не написал, моя вина. Количество сайтов постоянно меняется, поэтому выдавать собственного юзера каждому сайту возможности нет (нет прав у меня для этого банально, это не мой проект, а суперпользователя мне никто на даст), поэтому первые два пункта не подойдут.
А вот с представлениями уже интереснее, буду копать в этом направлении.

Comment: @Mateil А представления вам тоже не помогут, если отдельных пользователей нет. Хотя, я не работал никогда с mysql, там есть схемы, как в postgres/oracle? Если есть, то можно коннектится к разным схемам, тогда в каждой схеме можно сделать свое view, то есть каждый будет писать `select * from my_view` и получать разные данные.

Comment: Представления почти наверняка затормозят работу с базой. Впрочем, если БД - это лишь интерфейсные заморочки, то это и неважно.

Comment: @Akina Затормозят??? MySQL даже ужаснее, чем я представлял до этого :)))

Comment: @Dmitry Ну представьте, что вьювы объёмны и захотят материализоваться... от этого же ни одна СУБД не застрахована...